# How format latex code in []

Tags: formatting

What editor allows you to do automatic indentation as in the example in []
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSH0s.png)

[image]

If I use TexStudio it does so

Or is it all done by hand?

Comment: Mark everything within [], menu bar -> idefix -> indent. Voilá!

Comment: Yes, it worked and it looks like I need to read the program documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Texstudio has a function to automatically indent stuff:

- Mark everything within `[]`
- `menu bar -> idefix -> indent`